# Keep spawning Fire Ants AFTER completing Quest "Those!"

Tags: fallout-3

I'm testing out a mod that allows you to 'recruit' insects in the game. The mod works ok for the most part (sometimes the insects can't follow you through doors) but that's not why I'm here.

I had recruited two Fire Ant Soldiers which make an excellent addition to my army, and they were doing quite well. Except I then completed the quest 'Those!' (which is centred around the Fire Ants) and all the ants disappeared (including 'my' ants!)

- I at first thought it was a glitch in the mod, and went back to 'recruit' some more, but they had all disappeared.
- I then tried using the console to spawn some more - that worked, except they disappeared again within a couple of minutes.

I reloaded a save from before I completed the quest, and have been avoiding it, but I hate leaving a quest unfinished.

Last time I completed the quest by:

> Killing the Nest Guardians but leaving the Queen alive (as per Dr Lesko's request) and telling the kid to go to his Aunt in Rivet city (there was also an option to have him go to Little Lamplight).

**Is there a way to complete the quest that leaves the Fire Ant colony intact?**

**Edit:**

**-OR-**

**Is there a mod that allows for the continued spawning of the Fire Ants?**

Comment: looked around a bit, didn't find anything. Seems like the killing of the ants is scripted.

Comment: @Ids - Yeah I'm getting that impression as well. Perhaps there might be a mod that allows them to continue to spawn. I'll keep my eyes open for one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear that it's scripted my friend.

If you have some scripting experience yourself, there's a lot of easy accessible information on how to make mods and such.
If not, i would suggest lurking the http://fallout3.nexusmods.com/ forums for a modder looking for work. It's a minor incision and wouldn't be very time consuming, bettering your chances quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah I've played around with the modding tools before, (made a radio station). I'm considering giving it a crack myself. I have been lurking Nexus in my spare time (It's where I download mods from) but you're right perhaps someone out there would have more skills with the G.E.C.K. I'll give that a go